# Sed command to remove all lines not containing punctuation

Tags: sed

I'm struggling to find a sed command to remove all lines in a text file that do not contain punctuation (of any kind) without doing each manually.

For example:

```
111.222.123.234
222.11.34.54
word                   # To remove
www.facebook.com
www.stackoverflow.com
another                # To remove
random@email.com
```

Does such a command exist?

Comment: Did you actually try anything, this is extremely basic and could easily be searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[:punct:]` character class, which corresponds to

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]
```

and negate it:

```
$ sed '/[[:punct:]]/!d' infile
111.222.123.234
222.11.34.54
www.facebook.com
www.stackoverflow.com
random@email.com
```

Or, instead of the negated match, negate the character class directly:

```
sed '/[^[:punct:]]/d'
```

Or don't print anything unless a line *does* contain a punctuation character:

```
sed -n '/[[:punct:]]/p'
```

Or use grep instead of sed:

```
grep '[[:punct:]]' infile
```

Comment: Even grep works with that regex: `grep '[[:punct:]]' filename`

Comment: @glennjackman And would probably be faster! Mind if I add it?